# How do you make a rails route constraint that the first folder in path is an ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on an API and would like the URL's to look like `domain.com/v1/12345678/users/23` with the `12345678` translating to an account number.

I would like to pass the `12345678` to calls but cannot figure out how I can make a constraint for the routes AND how I can pull that ID in other calls.

I know if this was a subdomain, I could create a constraint for the routes file that restricts the routes to only those subdomains, and I could do something like `Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)` to grab the account info on other calls but I am drawing a blank trying to figure out how to do the same but with a PATH and not subdomain.

---

EDIT

I think I want my routes to look something like this

```
namespace :v1 do 
    scope ':account_id', :module => "account" do
        post '/users', :to => "users#create", default: :json
        get '/users', :to => "users#index", default: :json
        get '/users/:id', :to => "users#show", as: :user, default: :json
    end
end
```

Comment: So are you not wanting to treat that account id as a normal URL parameter?

Comment: I am a bit confused by your comment. Sorry?
I do want to treat it as a parameter that I can pass to each controller. So if that's what you mean then yes..

Comment: Sorry yeah your edit helped. Did you try `scope path: ":account_id", as: "account" do ... end`?